# Comparing two lists can't work.JAVA Spring

Tags: java, spring

I've got my class of java "Controller", which have to update my new list

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<UsersGroup> updateUsersGroup(@RequestBody List<UsersGroup> newUsersGroup, Integer id){
    List<UsersGroup> oldGroup = serwis.getUsersGroup(id);
    return serwis.updateUsersGroup(oldGroup, newUsersGroup);
}
```

and then i've got simple Service class:

```
public List<UsersGroup> updateUsersGroup(List<UsersGroup> oldGroup, List<UsersGroup> newGroup) {    
    List<UsersGroup> result = oldGroup.stream().filter(elem -> !newGroup.contains(elem)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return result;
}
```

I've got one list with all users and another list with group of users. When i click "Save" nothing happens. No error, no success, just nothing.

Comment: The debugger is your friend.

Comment: for your class `UsersGroup` did you override hashcode and equals method?

Comment: And why don't you just use `removeAll()`? `oldGroup.removeAll(newUsersGroup)`